# ssh login taking too long

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a hardware which is flashed with the following operating system :
Linux colibri 2.6.26-colibri_pxa3xx #14
I have noticed that the ssh login as well as telnet takes too long, even though I try to login from the same subnet.

I do not see any unusual messages being logged in the /var/log/messages

I tried ssh -vvv and I can see that the delay is mainly due to the fetch in the remote protocol version. I have 2 identical machines flashed with the same OS and the behaviour occurs in one and not the other.
The lag i see is a considerable delay in fetching and displaying this message.

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.49
```

Comment: Use `ssh -vvv` to see where does it hang? Have you tried to disable DNS Reverse lookup on the server?

Comment: Is your ssh authenticating to ldap? Possibly the LDAP is the hangup.

Comment: Maybe check this post out, he uses strace to look into a slow ssh connection. Might be able to follow steps and see where its coming from http://www.depesz.com/2010/12/13/a-tale-of-slow-ssh-connections/

Answer (score 2):

First, to collect more info about the delay try connecting with verbosity enabled: `ssh -vvv user@hostname`. 
Second, try disabling the reverse DNS lookup - edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on your device and setup `UseDNS no`. Restart the service and check again.
Third, setup `GSSAPIAuthentication no` in the same file, restart the service and retry.

[Here](http://www.walkernews.net/2009/04/06/how-to-fix-scp-and-ssh-login-prompt-is-very-slow-in-linux/) you can see a good example, I used it in the past.

Comment: Thanks! I had to set `UseDSN no` and `GSSAPIAuthentication no`, then I restarted the `sshd` service with `sudo service ssh restart` and the next time I connected it was instantaneous!

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `UseDNS no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart ssh. 
You may also want to add an entry to `/etc/hosts` for the machine you are trying ssh into.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue connecting to my DC. Try to alter the MTU settings of the sshd server to a value less than 1500. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem: the SSH connection took 22 seconds with authorization key. Used `ssh -vvv user@remote_host` to see this message:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
```

Then [this link](http://casesup.com/knowledgebase/how-to-fix-debug1-unspecified-gss-failure-error/) showed:
"add  host to  /etc/hosts  file."
So I added the `remote_host` on client's `/etc/hosts`. Now the SSH connection takes less than second.

Comment: This does not match the information in the original question. If the error you encountered is not part of anything existing, this may be posted as a new question. You can also answer it yourself just to provide the information.